# 404 error on uploading project from localhost to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to upload a codeigniter project from my local system to the server.
I have made necessary changes to my config/database.php and changed my base_url to point to $config['base_url'] = 'http://hrlwebproducts.com/non-disclosure-agreement/';  since i want to run the whole project inside the folder named non-disclosure-agreement.

Now everything is working fine on localhost. When i click on submit button in the login page it takes me to the secure page and the url on my browser changes to http://localhost/non-disclosure-agreement/index.php/verifylogin and it displays the page correctly but when i press the submit button of my login page on my server and try to access this secure page the url is http://hrlwebproducts.com/non-disclosure-agreement/index.php/verifylogin  and i get a error.

404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

I have no clue about the error.

My view code is:

```html
 <div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
    <p id="heading">NDA</p>
    <p>If not registered then click here..<a href="<?php $this->load->helper('url'); echo site_url('welcome/') ?>">register</a></p>

   <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
     
     <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
     <br/>

     <input type="password" size="20" id="password" name="password"/>
     <br/>
         <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="terms">I have read all the <a href="<?php $this->load->helper('url'); echo site_url('welcome/linkroutes') ?>">Terms & Conditions</a><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
   </form>
 
 </div>
    </div>
```

My controller is VerifyLogin and code is:

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 /**
  * Index Page for this controller.
  *
  * Maps to the following URL
  *   http://example.com/index.php/welcome
  * - or -
  *   http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
  * - or -
  * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
  * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
  *
  * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
  * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
  * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
  */
  
  
 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
       $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
 }
 
 public function index()
 {
  
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
 
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');
 
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('Password', 'text dont match captcha');
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
  $this->load->view('dashboard');
   }
 }
 
 
  function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');
 
   //query the database
   $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);
   $this->load->library('session');
 
   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'id' => $row->id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }
 }    
 
  public function linkroutes()
 {
  $this->load->view('dashboard');
 }
 
  public function linkroutestoform()
 {
  
    $this->load->view('formfill');
    

 }
}
```

My .htaccess file is

```html
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Check that your 'routes.php' file is up to date on the live server.

Comment: It is : $route['default_controller'] = 'VerifyLogin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: try using form_open('VerifyLogin/index').

Comment: awesome .. it worked.. wats going on ?

Comment: I think you need to change in your htaccess file

Comment: is it..? how do i do that?

Comment: It was an upper lower case problem. You need to provide the action as the same case as of your controller name.

Comment: oh.. but here is another problem in one more page and submit button.. <a id="submit" href="<?php $this->load->helper('url'); echo base_url('Home/indexes') ?>">submit</a> for the controller file.. class Home extends CI_Controller {... now where is the problem it displays 404 again

Comment: it is htaccess issue, please share it or place /foldername in redirect line of htaccess

Comment: this is my .htaccess file: <IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>